# What is the lightest linux environment can you mount in GitHub actions

Tags: github-actions

I'd like to know what is the lightest image you can mount to run a CI pipeline in GitHub Actions.

Currently, a scheduled workflow is ran every two hours a day.

If I understand the process well, an `ubuntu-latest` is mounted each time to run the jobs ?

```yaml
jobs:
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

I'm afraid to have a costly impact with my numeric uses, and would like to reduce them at most.

So while I want to benefit from these wonderful features, **I'd like to know if there is a very minimalist environment to run bash commands** ?

Comment: What is the problem with `ubuntu-latest`? Ubuntu is the only linux distribution that is provided as a github hosted runner. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/specifications-for-github-hosted-runners#supported-runners-and-hardware-resources

Comment: Anecdotally I've noticed `ubuntu-20.04` to be the fastest runner OS when doing matrix builds. `ubuntu-latest` still points to 18.04 (they're warning about it changing to 20.04 soon™, though), so it's not currently the fastest runner. Another way OP may want to consider speeding up runs is using [caching](https://github.com/actions/cache).

Comment: @DannyB there is no problem, but I would like to ensure using the "cheapest" image to run. But apparently there is only one option

Comment: @jidicula It's not only about speed but also soberty

Comment: GitHub Actions are rated by minutes of execution, so I was defaulting to speed as a proxy for your cost motivation. Unless you’re referring to some other cost?

Comment: @jidicula Yeah I guess we won't get more than time as measurement of our activities. We could imagine let's say energy consumption